# How to send email notifications with action mailer once payment has been successful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need help on this rails challenge, I have a model that accepts payment, and payment is working fine with Mollie's payment API, and in the dashboard I see the amounts, but I want to be able to send email notifications once payment has been successful, currently, email notifications are not getting sent even after implementing sending emails with action mailer.

Here is my code:

```
class DonationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_donation, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  def new
    @donation = Donation.new
  end

  def create
    @donation = Donation.create donation_params

    flash[:success] = "Thanks for your awesome contribution!"
    payment = Mollie::Payment.create(
      amount:  @donation.amount,
      description:  'Thank you for contributing',
      redirect_url: "https://ejoka.com",
      webhook_url:  "https://ejoka.com/donations/callback"
    )

    @donation.payments.create(
                   amount: @donation.amount, 
                   name: @donation.name, 
                   email: @donation.email, 
                   donation_id: @donation.id, 
                   identifier: payment.id
                  )
 
  
    redirect_to payment.checkout_url, { allow_other_host: true }
  end

  def callback
    unless params[:testByMollie]
      id = params[:id]
      payment = Mollie::Payment.get(id)
      if payment.paid?
        pay = Payment.find_by_identifier id
        @donation = pay.donation
        @donation.has_been_paid(pay)
      end
    end
  end
 

  private
    def set_donation
      @donation = Donation.find(params[:id])
    end

    def donation_params
      params.require(:donation).permit(:name, :email, :amount, :paid)
    end
end
```

Here is my model

```
class Donation < ApplicationRecord
  validates :amount, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true

  scope :paid, -> {where(paid: :true)}
  
  has_many :payments

  def has_been_paid(pay)
    pay.update paid: true
    self.update paid: true
    DonationMailer.donation_created(self).deliver_now     
    DonationMailer.new_donation(self).deliver_now    
  end
end
```

Payment model

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :donation, optional: true
end
```

My Mailer

```
class DonationMailer < ApplicationMailer

   def donation_created(donation)
     @donation = donation

     mail to: @donation.email, subject: "Thank You for Your Contribution"
   end

  def new_donation(donation)
   @donation = donation 

   mail to: @donation.email, subject: "Thank You for Your Donation"
  end
end
```

Mailer views

```
donation_created.html.erb

Hi,

Thank you for your donation of @donation.amount
```

```
new_donation.html.erb

Thank you for your donation of @donation.amount
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? I see that your code is supposed to call the `DonationMailer` in your `has_been_paid` method. Are you saying that the method itself is working but the emails are still not sent? Is there any error? Or anything is written into the log file when you run that method? Is your mailer correctly configured?

Comment: In my method of has_been_paid, if I add the DonationMailer inside, I don't get any email after a successful donation, but if I remove the DonationMailer from my method of has_been_paid and put it inside the create method in tthe DonationController, I get email notification but its before payment is made, I want email notifications to be sent after making a successful payment. @spickermann

Answer (score 0):

there is 2 condition in your callback

```
unless params[:testByMollie]
```

has to be a false value

and the second is

```
if payment.paid?
```

has to be true for has_been_paid to be called

you can easily print the output of both